# JavaFX launch method outside the main?

Tags: java, javafx, program-entry-point

How do you activade the launch(); tag in javaFX outside the main method?

Sth. like that works:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
   launch(args);
}

public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
...
}
```

but sth. like that not:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
   HelloWorld hw = new HelloWorld(args);
}

public HelloWorld(String[] args){
   launch(args);
}

public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
...
}
```

why? and how can i fix it, so i dont have to put the lauch method in the main everytime?

Comment: Why don't you want to put it in main?

Comment: `launch()` creates an instance of the `Application` subclass by (effectively) calling the zero-argument constructor. Since your second example doesn't have a zero-argument constructor, you'll get a runtime exception. You can make it work by adding a zero-argument constructor in addition to the one you have, though it's a bit redundant. Why not use the standard process?

Comment: Not to mention that as launch creates an instance of your HelloWorld application and you are also create a new instance of HelloWorld instance in main, you will have two instances of your HelloWorld application, which is probably not what you want.

Comment: Additionally, perhaps you are a thinking that if you launch somewhere else, then you might be able to launch on demand, effectively launching the same application multiple times from a running JVM.  Perhaps you are not thinking that, but if you were, it won't work because launch "[must not be called more than once or an exception will be thrown](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/application/Application.html#launch-java.lang.String...-)".

Comment: @Natecat: because your code may do more things besides displaying JavaFX? And/or because the JavaFX views are just an add-on to the core functionality.